# FormGroup binding between TS and HTML

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am trying for the first time to make a Reactive form in Angular

Here is the code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-username-password',
  templateUrl: './username-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./username-password.component.scss']
})
export class UsernamePasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    userName : new FormControl("Ashish"),
    password : new FormControl("")

  });

  // constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Login Form</h2>
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm">
        <label> User Name</label>
        <input formControlName="userName" , type="text" , class="form-control">
    </form>
    {{loginForm.value | json}}
</div>
```

The HTML is not displaying anything.

Is there a mistake in it?

I am getting this error in comments
[image]

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: `<input formControlName="userName" , type="text" , class="form-control">` there should be no commas. And even after removing commas still don't work, can you check console for any errors

Comment: That is not the case. Even after removing comas, Its not working. Even if I comment INPUT , atleaset Label should be displayed. Even Label is not displayed.

Comment: Yeah, there it is. I think you not imported `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: Why unaccepted the answer after one day, is there anything wrong in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `ReactiveFormsModule` to your `app.module.ts` like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';



@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` in the `AppModule` or specific module where your component resides

**Eg:**

```
...

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ...,
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-username-password',
  templateUrl: './username-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./username-password.component.scss']
})

export class UsernamePasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;

  // constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
          userName : new FormControl("Ashish"),
          password : new FormControl("")
        });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it seems to me that you have not imported the `ReactiveFormsModule` in your module that contains this component.